# an auto-increment version in document creation mongoose

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose

I want that when a new document is created the versionKey (__v) field will auto-increment.

(or should I use a new field 'version' instead __v in the schema?)

example for the schema in my app :

**Template.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Test = require('./Test');

var TemplateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  platform: String,
  templateRevision: String,
  tests: [Test.schema]
});

TemplateSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.increment();
  return next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Template', TemplateSchema);
```

**routes/templatesApi.js**

```
// create new template document
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Test.create(req.body, function (err, tests) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(tests);
    });
});
```

where and how can I insert the auto-increment operation for versionKey property here?

Edit: I tried to use `.pre('save')` middleware and it still not working.

am I using it right?

Comment: @turivishal   I saw that answer but I'm a beginner in with Mongo and I don't know how should I implement it with the '.create' function that I'm using.
where should I insert the schema.pre("save") here?

Comment: But `create()` will create new document right? then why you want to increment version in create? and by default zero will be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Customize __v key name

Yes we can change `__v` default key name to any custom [versionKey](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey)

```
var TemplateSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    platform: String,
    templateRevision: String,
    tests: [Test.schema]
  },
  { versionKey: 'version' }
);
```

#### Auto increment version

> below middleware will call before operation and update incremented version,

- Increment when `save()`, `this` refers to **document** object

```
TemplateSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.increment();
    return next();
});
```

- increment when `updateMany()`, `this` refers to **query** object

```
TemplateSchema.pre('updateMany', function(next) {
    this.updateMany({}, { $inc: { version: 1 } });
    return next()
});
```

Same way you can create middleware for other methods `update()`, `updateOne()`, `findOneAndUpdate()`, `findAndModify()` and etc.

- we are working in Template.js file and last you need to create a model for schema and export, that you have already did.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Template', TemplateSchema);
```

#### Examples

- load models

```
const Template = require('./Template'); // manage path of Template.js
```

- find one and save

```
let doc = Template.findOne({ _id: "5f299bdbf045394388fc1461" });
doc.platform = "test platform";
doc.save(); // before this, `save` middleware will call and auto increment version by 1
```

- update multiple documents

```
Template.updateMany(
    { platform: "test platform" },
    { $set: { platform: "demo platform" } }
);
// before this, `updateMany` middleware will call and increment version by 1
```